# Prevent smart reply buttons appearing for Gmail users who receive my emails

Tags: gmail

Is there any way to add content to an email that will prevent the smart reply buttons from showing in a Gmail recipients mailbox? I am sending emails to clients that I do not want the smart reply buttons to show up in their Gmail app as they are incorrect and misleading.

Comment: Checkout [Resources for Senders](https://developers.google.com/gmail/design/) from Google Developers

Comment: @Rubén i looked through it but couldnt find anything specific to the smart reply buttons. looks like i would be able to add my own actions but the smart reply buttons would probably still show

Comment: @jeffreypriebe I think this is the opposite problem.  In the proposed duplicate, the user is trying to get rid of the icons from their *own* inbox.

Comment: @jonsca, you are absolutely correct. I was moving too fast, *this is not a duplicate* - a logician could tell us what it actually is.

Comment: @jeffreypriebe It is absolutely no problem whatsoever.  I did the same thing on an SO question last night :) Thanks for your diligence.

Comment: As of October 2018, it's [finally possible to turn this feature off in your own inbox](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/121319/45078), but there doesn't seem to be any way to stop the fake-reply buttons appearing in your recipients' inboxes. If your clients dislike the feature, you can suggest they turn it off themselves using that linked setting.

Answer (score 1):

As of October 2018 you can now make a change to your settings that will prevent this feature appearing on emails you receive. That change will apply to emails even if they aren't from Gmail users.

You can think of it a special filter that is applied to incommoding emails. If the application believes the smart_reply filter applies, then you will see the smart reply options when you read the email.

Because it is a special filter on incoming email, you have no ability to modify settings on the recipients Gmail account. If they allowed you that power it would be dangerous.